# Https setup for spring boot and swagger2

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, keycloak, keytool

I am trying to integrate my Sprint Boot applications with Keycloak, starting with secure swagger page.

keytool helped me to generate a selfsigned keystore

```
keytool -genkey -alias abcdef -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048  -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
```

I use the above to setup ssl for the app

```
server:
  port: "15700"
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password
    key-alias: abcdef
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
```

Without keycloak, the https for swagger works as expected.

I started keycloak from their docker image as below, export http and https

```
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: my.ip.address
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: username
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
      - 8080:8080
```

I ask user to login first when they want to access the swagger docs, so I configure keycloak as below:

```
keycloak:
   auth-server-url: "https://192.168.1.15:8443/auth"
   realm: "DemoRealm"
   public-client: true
   resource: demo-app
   security-constraints[0]:
     authRoles[0]: "user"
     securityCollections[0]:
       name: "Demo App"
       patterns[0]: "/swagger-ui.html"
```

Now, not logged in user will be direct to keycloak login page, it works perfect. But after the successful login, when redirect back to the app's swagger page, I go the following error:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

If I configure the keycloak auth uri to http

```
keycloak:
   auth-server-url: "http://192.168.1.15:8080/auth"
   realm: "DemoRealm"
   public-client: true
   resource: demo-app
   security-constraints[0]:
     authRoles[0]: "user"
     securityCollections[0]:
       name: "Demo App"
       patterns[0]: "/swagger-ui.html"
```

everything works perfectly.

Is this a configuration issue for keycloak or for the spring boot app? Any required steps I missed?

Comment: Can you please try with .jks for key-store parameter.

Comment: @RaheelaAslam Tried using JKS format, see the same error. Generating in JKS format, "Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12". My guess is that PKCS12 is the format to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set up your Rest Template bean:

1. Add dependency:

   ```
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
   ```
2. Provide RestTemplate bean:

```java
@Bean
private RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        SSLContext sslContext = buildSslContext();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }

private SSLContext buildSslContext() {
        try {
            char[] keyStorePassword = sslProperties.getKeyStorePassword();
            return new SSLContextBuilder()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(
                            KeyStore.getInstance(new File(sslProperties.getKeyStore()), keyStorePassword),
                            keyStorePassword
                    ).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to instantiate SSL context", ex);
        } finally {
            sslProperties.setKeyStorePassword(null);
            sslProperties.setTrustStorePassword(null);
        }
    }
```

3. Provide required SSL properties in your application.properties or application.yaml file:

```
server:
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-store: /path/to/key.keystore
        key-store-password: password
        key-alias: alias
        trust-store: /path/to/truststore
        trust-store-password: password
```

Alternatively, you can use [my spring boot starter](https://github.com/EugeneLesnov/spring-boot-starter-rest)